# Are virtual micro black holes being considered in feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

I wonder if above some energies (or diagram level?) the virtual particles would rather behave (or become) like a micro black hole. Does that make sense? Could this somehow introduce a cut off above which Feynman diagrams would be unnecessary (the micro black holes would always evaporate in perhaps a few different ways), and in doing so avoid renormalization? This are speculations from a freshman, so please don't be hard on me.

Comment: Feynman diagrams are used in quantum field theory models to simplify the calculations, so a QFT for micro black holes could be used in models of quantized gravity. It will not be simple, in the way you visualize in the question..

Comment: It basically comes down to introducing the Planck scale as a cut-off, which is not a new idea. It is at this hypothetical scale where such black hole dynamics would presumably start to appear. However, such a notion is non-scientific in the sense that it has not been (and in practice cannot be) confirmed by experimental observations.

Comment: There’s no accepted theory of quantum gravity, so your question is unclear on what theory you would be using.

Comment: @Ghoster why not start with a semiclassical approach? the question is if there is a way to include that in feynman diagrams in a more or less direct way, I am not asking anyone to develop a new theory, just see what intuitions people with deeper knowledge  can tell about the subject. Unfortunately these kind of questions are censored.